# ExPex no longer available

Tags: linguistics, expex

I have noticed that the excellent linguistic package ExPex is no longer available on the [website of the maintainer](http://www.math.neu.edu/ling/tex/). (This package is not in CTAN and was only maintained there.) Does anyone know why? Is it no longer being developed?

Comment: It was available in at least April 2013, as archived at the internet archive http://web.archive.org/web/20130406110113/http://www.math.neu.edu/ling/tex/expex/

Comment: Since John Frampton is retired from Northeastern University, where he taught for many years, it's likely that his university web space has been discontinued. I've contacted him about this, and will report back when I hear from him.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am a little afraid that this package will be stopped and there will be compatibility problems then in the future. Because I have used expex heavily in my thesis and the thesis will still take a long time.

Comment: Regarding future compatibility problems, one solution might be to 'freeze' a setup that works that you can fall back on, if needed.  An [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116797/8528) I gave to a rather different question might be adaptable to this purpose.

Comment: I've contacted John and he was unaware of the webspace issue, and will get it fixed. He has no intention of abandoning the package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I contacted the author of ExPex (John Frampton) and he was unaware of the web page issue.  The issue has now been resolved, and the [link in the question](http://www.math.neu.edu/~ling/tex/) has been changed (although the link in the question now redirects there). He has no intentions of abandoning development of the package. It is likely that it will be uploaded to CTAN in the future.

Until the package is released on CTAN, users should continue to use this link to get the current version of the package.

### Update

ExPex has now been submitted to [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/expex), so users should use their package manager or the CTAN website to keep their version up to date.

Comment: OK thanks I'll delete my answer to avoid confusion