# Is there a way to create a standalone folder/document with non standard packages?

Tags: packages, package-options

I am working on an article which will be compiled on another machines (of somebody else). I don't want to depend on the other person to install missing packages. Is there a way to include them with the folder I'll send him?

Comment: You can download the packages from CTAN and put them (and compile them) in a directory of your project and include them from there. But I think you don't want to download the packages one-by-one. Do you want this to be done automatically?

Comment: @SándorKazi What do you mean by "done automatically"?

Comment: Automatically, so you don't want/have to download the packages one-by-one manually. I don't think it is possible, but is that what you want?

Comment: Do you want something like http://ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc with http://ctan.org/pkg/snapshot? Or maybe http://ctan.org/pkg/arlatex?

Comment: @SándorKazi Yes, exactly

Comment: @cfr bundledoc sounds right. I'm not certain what arlatex does.

Comment: @Yotam I'm not sure either but I think it combines things into one file somehow. bundledoc seemed more likely given your description. I just mentioned the other as it came up as an alternative when I got the ctan link for bundledoc.

Comment: @cfr Cool!. What term did you search ?

Comment: @Yotam I don't remember exactly. I just knew I'd seen *something* which could do this but couldn't remember quite what. I know I tried things like 'archive' and 'publish' but I might eventually have thought 'bundle' as it took me a few guesses to get useful results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've answered a similar question before (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116797/8528)), but maybe you just want to give them one file rather than a whole archive containing all the files.  If so, this is one possibility, assuming this 'projectfile.tex':

```
% projectfile.tex
\RequirePackage{snapshot}% <-- this *must* be used! 
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{parskip}%      <-- pretend this is a file your partner doesn't have
\begin{document}
Some words.
\end{document}
```

Now, you run `latex` (or `pdflatex`, etc.) on `projectfile.tex`. Among the files created is `projectfile.dep` (via the `snapshot` package).  Now we want to combine the power of `arlatex` and `bundledoc` to create one file that has, via the `filecontents` package *all* the files required to successfully process `projecttile.tex` (i.e., from `article.cls` to `parskip.sty`).  If you include many packages, this file will get ridiculously big, which is why outputting it to an archive file probably makes more sense.  However, maybe size isn't an issue....

Next we need a `.cfg` for `bundledoc`.  For Windows, the variables will be slightly different, but this is what I used (let's call it `arlatex+bundledoc.cfg`):

```sh
# config file 'arlatex+bundledoc.cfg'
bundle: (arlatex --document=$BDBASE.tex $BDINPUTS > $BDBASE-all.tex)
sink:   > /dev/null 2>&1 
find:   kpsewhich -progname=latex $BDINPUTS
```

Now we run the `bundledoc` command (`--verbose` might be a good idea, at least when you're starting out):

```sh
bundledoc --config=arlatex+bundledoc.cfg --verbose projectfile.dep
```

This should create a file called `projectfile-all.tex`.  Test it by running `latex` (etc.) on it and `diff`-ing the resulting output with the output of `projectfile.tex`.

As I said, this process is likely to create monster files, so it probably makes more sense to output to a compressed file of some sort (see the other answer), or simply use `arlatex` to include the *specific* files that are needed for portability.

**Edit:**

In other words, the basic procedure involves these steps:

1. Create your file as you normally would (e.g., via `pdflatex`);
2. When you are ready to use `bundledoc`, add the line `\RequirePackage{snapshot}` at/near the top of your `.tex` file (must be above the `\documentclass` line);
3. Compile main `.tex` once again to create the `.dep` file;
4. Ensure you have a viable config (`.cfg`) file for `bundledoc` (easiest to keep it in the working directory);
5. Run `bundledoc` with the `.cfg` file on the `.dep` file

If all goes well, and if you used file names similar to the ones in this example, you will end up with a file called `-all.tex`.

Answer (score 4):

A combination of [bundledoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc) and [snapshot](http://ctan.org/pkg/snapshot) may meet your requirements. Although I've not used these myself, as I understand it snapshot can make a list of all the files and packages required to compile your document. bundledoc can then gather those files and packages together so that they can be easily bundled with your document for sharing with others.