# How to use 'Bundledoc', 'Snapshot' and 'Arlatex'?

Tags: archiving, bundledoc

I am writing a document and I want to share it with some partners I have been searching around and I found that `Bundledoc`, `Snapshot` and `arlatex` could help me to create my document and share it. The only problem is that I do not know how to use them. I already read [Is there a way to create a standalone folder/document with non standard packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152786/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-standalone-folder-document-with-non-standard-packages) but I do not know where to write the `bundle` and `arlatex` commands. Inside the same LaTeX document, in another document, or in the terminal?

Comment: Note: I incorporated my (erased) comments into the answer linked to in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Jon and his answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152786/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-standalone-folder-document-with-non-standard-packages) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116719/how-can-i-balance-uniformity-of-style-files-against-modularity/116797#116797) I could do what I was intended to. As a short precedure of using bundledoc, and arlatex+bundledoc we could follow the next steps:

1. Create your file as you normally would (e.g., via pdflatex);
2. When you are ready to use bundledoc, add the line \RequirePackage{snapshot} above the \documentclass line.
3. Compile main .tex once again to create the .dep file.
4. Ensure you have a viable config (.cfg) file for bundledoc (easiest to keep it in the working directory).
5. If not you can create the .cfg file, and save it in the working directory:

---

`# basic config file for use of arlatex + bundledoc
bundle: (arlatex --document=$BDBASE.tex $BDINPUTS | tar -cvf - $BDINPUTS | gzip --best > $BDBASE-all.tar.gz )
sink:   > /dev/null 2>&1
find:   kpsewhich -progname=latex $BDINPUTS`

---

(This is for compiling arlatex and bundledoc at the same time)

6. Run bundledoc with the .cfg file on the .dep file

If all goes well, and if you used file names similar to the ones in this example, you will end up with a file called -all.tex.