# bundledoc: Troubleshooting with "No such file or directory (miktex.cfg)"

Tags: bundledoc

Recently I have heard about the `bundledoc` package and wanted to test it. I use a fairly simple test file similar to the one shown in the documentation.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{snapshot} 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I also put the `miktex.cfg` file from the package directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\bundledoc` in the working directory.

[image]

I also was able to generate the `dep` file (`test.dep`) by running `pfdlatex`.

```
\RequireVersions{
  *{application}{TeX}     {1990/03/25 v3.x}
  *{format} {LaTeX2e}     {2017-04-15 v2.e}
  *{package}{snapshot}    {2002/03/05 v1.14}
  *{class}  {article}     {2014/09/29 v1.4h}
  *{file}   {size10.clo}  {2014/09/29 v1.4h}
  *{package}{amsmath}     {2017/09/02 v2.17a}
  *{package}{amstext}     {2000/06/29 v2.01}
  *{package}{amsgen}      {1999/11/30 v2.0}
  *{package}{amsbsy}      {1999/11/29 v1.2d}
  *{package}{amsopn}      {2016/03/08 v2.02}
}
```

**But I fail to run the `bundledoc` command. I use the following batch file (Windows 10) with administrator privileges.**

```
bundledoc --config=miktex.cfg --verbose test.dep
pause
```

And I get

> No such file or directory (miktex.cfg)

[image]

Strangely enough, when I run the batch file *without* administrator privileges then I get another error (`command zip not found` in German).

[image]

> I am on a business trip this week and won't be able to be very
>   responsive. I would be happy if someone could test my setting and tell
>   me if it works on his/her machine.

### Hidden Agenda

I will give a LaTeX introduction to Ph.D. students in the summer and wanted to test `bundledoc` before that. If the test is successful then I will recommend `bundledoc` as a way to "freeze" one's LaTeX version for a long-term preservation or/and a safeguard for problems after updating the LaTeX distribution.

My favorite solution, however, is to use a virtual machine, but that's not important here.

### Update

- Thanks to the comments it now boils down to utilize a zip program.
- Apparently, I do not have `zip` available on the command line.
- I installed 7zip and added the path to the exe (`C:\Program Files\7-Zip`) to the PATH variable in Windows.
- But I do now know how to configure the `miktex.cfg` correctly.

[image]

```
# bundledoc configuration file for MikTeX
# By Scott Pakin <scott+bdoc@pakin.org>

# ASSUMPTION: You have "zip" somewhere in your path, and it accepts the
#             command-line options utilized by the "bundle" line below.

rem bundle: zip -r -v -9 %BDBASE%.zip %BDINPUTS%
bundle: 7z.exe %BDBASE%.zip %BDINPUTS%
sink:   > NUL:
find:   kpsewhich -progname=latex %BDINPUTS%
```

### Related

- [How to use 'Bundledoc', 'Snapshot' and 'Arlatex'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185181/)
- [Is there a way to create a standalone folder/document with non standard packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152786/)
- [How can I balance uniformity of style files against modularity?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116719)

Comment: I didn't test but really the last thing I would do is to start a command in C:\windows\system32. And I wouldn't run such tests with admin privileges.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the comment. Apparently, I was misleading in my description: I did not run the batch file in `C:\windows\system32`. I just copied the needed `miktex.cfg` from there to my test directory (`D:\Downloads\delete.me\bundledoc` in my case).

Comment: But the screenshot you show us of the cmd is in `C:\windows\system32` so you did run `bundledoc` in that directory.

Comment: @Skillmon You are right, but I think has to do with something different. But I am not a software expert but I just double-click the batch file in the mentioned test folder. I could imagine that the Windows batch exe is in `C:\windows\system32`. I am using batch files for many years now and I always used them the described way.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks to your hint I did now test it without admin privileges and got another error (zip command missing). I am afraid this has nothing to do with LaTeX.

Comment: Yes it is (I guess), but if you run a batch file you see the working directory (the stuff just before `>`, which in the first screenshot is `C:\WINDOWS\system32>`). `zip` seems to be unavailable on your Windows machine. I don't know what you need to do to install it -- I'll go search for that.

Comment: Well in miktex.cfg there are the lines "ASSUMPTION: You have "zip" somewhere in your path, and it accepts the command-line options utilized by the "bundle" line below."

Comment: @Skillmon Ahhhhh - I now see what you and @UlrikeFischer mean. Indeed, that is strange. I don't know why `C:\windows\system32` is used when I start the batch file with admin privileges.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.info-zip.org/Zip.html). That might/should be the right executable (but I'm not entirely sure).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the hint. I will try to solve it. by installing a zip program.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for the hint. I will try to make it work with 7zip.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You were right. The assumption is not met in my case. But configuring the config file is beyond my capabilities. I tried to use 7zip and just replaced zip with 7zip.exe. But the options don't work. I think that we/I can put the question on hold because it's not about LaTeX anymore. maybe zip is available on Linux systems by default.

Comment: @Skillmon  I tried to use 7zip and just replaced zip with 7zip.exe. But the options don't work. I think that we/I can put the question on hold because it's not about LaTeX anymore. Maybe zip is available on Linux systems by default. The link you provided is also promising but I do not want to dig any deeper into a software that was last updated in 2009 :). I guess, that I won't recommend `bundledoc` after all,

Comment: I can confirm that `zip` is available on Linux, but there I'd use a compressed tarball and not zip.