# Is there a way to put some of my project's files in a separate folder?

Tags: packages, compiling, directory

My university has provided a thesis project template with tons of files in it. My current working directory looks a bit like this:

```
package1.sty
package2.sty
package3.sty
classFile.bst
classFile.cls
ttlps.def
logo.ps
... lots of other stuff ...
mythesis.tex    <-- these are the only files I work with
chapter01.tex   <--
chapter02.tex   <--
```

I was wondering if there is a good way to move all those files "out of the way", without installing them globally (all these packages are only useful for this specific project). Is there a way to make my directory structure look a bit more like this one?

```
out/    <--- .pdf, .dvi, .aux, .log, etc go here
stuff/  <--- all the custom packages, logos, etc go here.
mythesis.tex
chapter01.tex
chapter02.tex
```

I managed to separate the output files by passing a `--output-directory` flag when I invoke latex but I have no idea if there is a way to move all the other things to a separate folder. The closest I managed so far was to `cd` into the `stuff` folder when running latex but that forces me reference all my tex files as `../chapterXX` instead of `chapterXX`, even in `include` directives and things like that.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do what I want without needing to resort to extra tools such as snapshot or arlatex, as suggested in [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152786/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-standalone-folder-document-with-non-standard-packages)

Comment: Related: [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11123/5764)

Comment: Why don't you move all your `.tex` chapter files with into a new folder named `Chapters`. Then put `\input{Chapters/chapter01}` in your master file `mythesis.tex` to include them.

Comment: @alesc: I am already splitting my project into chapters. The problem is all those extra files from the thesis template. sty packages, cls files, logos, etc

Comment: This is possible with MiKTeX, if you're under windows.

Comment: I'm on Linux :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** The following works on all TeXLive-based distributions, but not with MikTeX.

I usually put stuff like this in a project-local `texmf` subfolder. To have `pdflatex` and others actually search this folder, it has to be added to the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable. I usually have a `sourceme.bash` file that I `source` in the shell:

```
export TEXINPUTS=./texmf//:${TEXINPUTS}
export BSTINPUTS=./texmf//:${BSTINPUTS}
export BIBINPUTS=./texmf//:${BIBINPUTS}
```

However, as I have started to do this in almost every project, I have recently added these lines to my login script, so that `pdflatex` looks for a `./texmf` folder in every case.

If you are using a Makefile, of course you could this for the purpose as well:

```
export TEXINPUTS := ./texmf//:${TEXINPUTS}
export BSTINPUTS := ./texmf//:${BSTINPUTS}
export BIBINPUTS := ./texmf//:${BIBINPUTS}
```

The double slash at the end of a path lets `pdflatex` recursively search the respective folder, so you could maintain a complete TDS-compliant texmf-tree inside.  Similar to `TEXINPUTS` for LaTeX style files, images, and `\input`s, there are many more environment variables available. The most important are:

- `BSTINPUTS` for BibTeX (and `biblatex`) style files.
- `BIBINPUTS` for the `.bib` files.
- `TEXFONTS` for additional (vector) fonts.

Comment: This doesn't put all the "output" files in a separate directory but I guess thats not a big deal now that all the input files are in a separate folder. Getting rid of the chaff becomes just a matter of doing a `rm -f *.aux *.log #...`

Comment: @hugomg: I didn't comment on the output part, as you have already solved it. `--output-directory` is the key. (I use it all the time.)

Comment: I'm having problems with dvips if I try to put things in a separate directory. Maybe it would work if I could change my template to use pdflatex directly.

Comment: Try to add the output directory itself to `TEXINPUTS`.  You may also consult `kpsewhich --show-path .pfa | less` to debut the search path.

Comment: The problem I am having now is that bibtex when I run `bibtex out/mythesis`, it fails with a `I couldn't open auxiliary file chapter01.aux` error. The only workaround I found was to use `\input{chapter01}` instead of `\include{chapter01}` but I'm not super fond of that...

Comment: Hm... I remember I had that problem as well, but don't know exactly how I solved it. It may help if you invoke `bibtex` from the `out` folder, i.e. `cd out;bibtex mythesis; cd-`. If you are using `biblatex` anyway (which I have been doing for a couple of years now), you could also use `biber`, which provides an `--output_directory` option.