# class and style files traversing up the directory tree?

Tags: texlive, kpathsea

texlive, osx/linux.

I believe it is impossible to place one's personal latex style and class files in a superior directory in the hierarchy, because of the way that the kpse library works (fixed directory index).  That is, I would have liked to place

```
/myjournal1
/myjournal1/journal.sty
/myjournal1/article1/document1.tex
/myjournal2
/myjournal2/journal.sty
/myjournal2/article1/document1.tex
/myjournal2/below/evenmorebelow/document2.tex
```

and each `.tex` file contains `\usepackage{journal}`.  The idea is to instruct `kpse` first to search up the directory tree and then further up into the standard local and global texmf tree, stopping when it finds a match.

There are at least two workarounds.  I can use symbolic links (which dropbox but not copy.com, promptly messes up).   Or I can explicitly refer to `\usepackage{../journal}`, when one level down, and so forth.

This is a minor nuisance, not a major hurdle.

/iaw

Comment: I'm confused. You don't normally have working documents in your TEXMF tree at all. You have these in some other directory. So this shouldn't be a problem. `journal.sty` goes in your personal TEXMF tree (or your local one or whatever) and the document you are writing lives outside that tree. [But I don't think that this wouldn't work if you did do it. It just strikes me as a bad idea to put these things in your TEXMF tree.]

Comment: If you don't want files in the working directory, then give things useful (i.e., *unique*) names, and put them in your TEXMF tree.  What is the point of having non-unique names?

Comment: yes, these were other alternatives: unique names and reorg.  alas, the reason for not wanting the journal.sty in my texmf hierarchy is that I often want to zip up document hierarchies for mailing to others.  having the ability to look back up dynamically until one finds a suitable match in the hierarchy is (sometimes) useful, even when it can be worked around.

Comment: The package [bundledoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc?lang=en) solves this problem quite nicely, in my opinion. I once [answered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116797/8528) a question that gives an overview of how it works (actually, kind of [twice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153077/8528)).  The other solution is to modify the TEXINPUTS variable, which you could do on per-directory basis -- or so I believe: I've never tried myself.