# Can I specify TeXLive version to install in the install-tl profile?

Tags: texlive, installing

In a TeXLive installation profile, can I specify a specific version or do I just get what I get?

I'm having versioning conflicts inside a Docker container which is supposed to be able to reliably build historical, tagged versions of my documentation, but (for reasons I've yet to completely ascertain) some difference between TeXLive 2007 and TeXLive 2015 (or package versions thereof) is preventing a build.

Ideally in this container I'd like to install TeXLive 2007, rather than TeXLive 2015, to match the environment in which the documents were originally created.

I am installing with `install-tl` because CentOS 6 does not distribute `tlmgr` and I want fine control of TeX package installation.

Comment: You can't install "historical" versions of TL using the default installer (at least, I don't think you can). But you can download any old version you like from [here](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/).  Of course, you do realize that having multiple versions of TL installed for your various containers will quickly eat up disk space!

Comment: @jon: That's not really avoidable; each container has its own toolchain anyway. I'm prepared for containers to take a few hundred megs; indeed, this is one of the reasons I'm using `tlmgr`, so I only install what I need. :) Anyway, if the default installer can't do this then that's the answer so I'd accept it if posted as such.

Comment: I'm happy to write that as an answer. However, you may also find this [other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116797/8528) of mine of interest. You can effectively create individual LaTeX file containers for each file you have written. The one thing to note in that case is that you won't be using the exact same engine as you were back (say) in 2007.  See also [this related answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153077/8528).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Contrary to the previously accepted answer by jon, it is possible to install an older version of TeX Live by [pointing the TeX Live installer](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-290003.3.1) to a repository from [the archive of historical versions of TeX Live](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/). This is how you would install TeX Live 2015:

```
./install-tl -repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final
```

It may be necessary to use the TeX Live installer for the specific TeX Live version, such as ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/install-tl.zip for TeX Live 2015.

Comment: Indeed a network installation possible all the way back to TeX Live 2011. It also works with HTTP using these links: http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2011/tlnet-final/ and `./install-tl -repository http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2011/tlnet-final` . TeX Live 2010 installs, but tlmgr is broken with Perl 5.24 on Linux (shows Perl errors).

Comment: You are exactly right. I see you discovered this thread before I even responded on the mailing list.

Comment: Here is a list of all mirrors for historic versions: https://www.tug.org/historic/ (some might be closer to you/faster)

Comment: it is VERY important to note that, the `install-tl` used in the above command must come from the same version of TL one is trying to install! else you will get an error.

Comment: So one has to go to the old repository and manually download `install-tl` from the folder of the version they want to install first. Then they can use the command shown above.

Comment: @Nasser That's already part of the answer, see the last paragraph.

Comment: @Witiko how would you install a version with a specific timestamp? Is that possible? Like,  if I install today the TexLive system today (version 2022) how can I do *exactly* the same in a month or two? There isn't a *final* version yet of the 2022 system for obvious reasons.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert: I don't think you can easily do that with TeX Live. You could mirror the TeX Live website to get a snapshot of the packages at a specific point in time or you could use a specific release of [the texlive/texlive Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/texlive/texlive), but neither is straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

An unofficial convenient installer of old TeX Live releases is now available from https://github.com/pts/historic-texlive .

It works on all Unix platforms, i.e. all platforms except for Windows (or Cygwin).

Answer (score 2):

The TeX Live installer is designed (I believe) to install only the current version of TeX Live, which means older versions are effectively "unmaintained". Of course, usually this is not a problem when you are purposely trying to use or access older packages.

So what you want to do is install the version you need. You can access older versions from this webpage: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html (click on the "Older releases of TeX Live" link).

As each TeX Live release is fairly large, you might want to consider trimming down the files you keep. For instance, in TL2015, the "doc" folder is 1.7 GB while fonts are 1.6 GB. If the purpose of the install is merely so you can recreate a few PDFs (etc.), you might want to consider removing some of the stuff you don't need.

Another idea would be to use the `bundledoc` and `arlatex` packages to create self-contained files that include precisely the version of each package which your `.tex` file needs. For this, you can look at these other answers of mine:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116797/8528
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153077/8528

Presumably, you could use the `bundledoc+arlatex` solution after you've installed the historical version of TeX Live of your choice, and then delete all the superfluous packages, fonts, and documentation. This should result in a very small Docker container.