# etex package still seems to be necessary in LaTeX2e 2015/10/01?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, e-tex, bytefield

I've experienced [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38609/19604) after upgrading to TeX Live 2015 and getting newer versions of all my packages. (Presumably some of those package updates are to blame.)

#### MVE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{bytefield}{32}
    \bitheader{0,8,16,24,32} \\
    \bitbox{16}{Kind} & \bitbox{16}{} \\
    \wordbox{3}{Payload} \\
\end{bytefield}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### TeX Live 2015, "LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 1":

```
! No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi
l.24    \bitbox{16}{Kind}
                        & \bitbox{16}{} \\
```

Installed on Fedora 22 using `install-tl`. All packages confirmed up-to-date with `tlmgr`.

#### TeX Live 2007, "LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>":

- Successful build

Installed using `yum install texlive texlive-latex texlive-dvips texlive-contex texlive-utils texlive-texmf-latex` on Fedora 11; some packages installed manually. Versions unknown (I could probably figure it out if needed.)

---

Adding `\usepackage{etex}` fixes it, which confuses me because I've heard LaTeX2e 2015/10/01 should have rendered that obsolete. Furthermore, I cannot simply add it to my LaTeX documents, because I cannot alter historical releases of my project and I wish for those to be buildable on my new system.

I *could* create an isolated build environment with my old package versions, to support these historical releases — indeed this is my plan B — but my old environment was clumsily configured (those manual package installs in particular) and I'd rather stick with the far more maintainable set up I have just created on my new server with shiny TeX Live 2015 (particularly as [we cannot request that `install-tl` automatically install old versions of TeX Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274870/19604)).

How should I resolve this? Can I somehow indicate to TeX Live, within the surrounding Linux environment, that this package is *always* to be used? (Then I could build my old documentation without altering its `.tex` or build commands. A shell alias of, say, `alias pdflatex=pdflatex -etex` would be acceptable, though passing `-etex` to `pdflatex` does not appear to remedy the problem for me.)

Or could you tell me why it seems to be necessary at all, and help me remove that factor?

Comment: The latest release of the LaTeX2e kernel should make the use of the `etex` package a historical thing. That said, it's a _package_ so can't be 'bundled up' with your choice of binary, unless you want to make a custom version of the LaTeX2e format which has it built in (but as I say, that really should not be needed).

Comment: @JosephWright: That's one of the reasons I'm a little confused. Why does `\usepackage{etex}` make a difference anyway when I'm installing TeX Live using `install-tl` and therefore (presumably) the latest version? Perhaps I'm missing something. `tex --version` says "TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015)".

Comment: note that the extended etex engine is used _always_ with latex in texlive, whether or not `\usepackage{etex}` is used. A package can not change the underlying engine, it just defined some macros that used the features of etex. It is almost never needed in 2015/01/01 latex but could be used to avoid some problems with `\newinsert` in special cases. In 2015/10/01 latex it should never be needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: MVE's up. Is this better/more actionable?

Comment: With MiKTeX I get no error.  Just a remark: `hyperref` should be the last called package and package `titlesec` is not recommended to be used with KOMA-Script (see resulting warning in the log file!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for the test file. That made it much easier to track down and check that **it's not my fault** which is of course the important thing:-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This issue is fixed in bytefield v2.3.**

Original answer follows.

---

The issue arises as the `bytefield` package trees to set up 'local' allocation of dimen registers. If `etex` is loaded it uses the functionality from that package but if not uses an 'internal' version of the original allocator code which ignores e-TeX and the kernel improvements. That can all be bypassed with

```
\let\locdimen\newdimen
```

anywhere before

```
\usepackage{bytefield}
```

A long-term solution is to get the package altered: the team will try to get that to happen.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like in my case the only solution is to downgrade everything (presumably my older package versions fit within original allocator limits by chance), or to wait?

Comment: I don't mind patching bytefield on my system; can I just plonk `\let\locdimen\newdimen` at the start of it? I might give that a go...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit we've mailed the author of the package, referencing your test file at this page, so hopefully this will get fixed soon.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that [this preamble](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275099/incompatible-list-cant-be-unboxed-with-memoir-class-and-many-box-registers/275117#275117) should be using `\locbox`? The original uses `\newbox` which requires `etex.sty` with current TL, whereas my version works just loading `ealloc.sty`. Er... I think. Not at all sure, really. But I know the other workarounds I have there are not correct (though they might be the only way to compile the document without alteration, which the OP needs).

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether [this](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.1371.1446147589.4389.ctan-ann@ctan.org) fixed the problem? I'm not seeing any changelogs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Change info in the docs says the release was to fix this issue, and running the MWE confirms it now works.

Comment: @JosephWright: Oh, so it does. That section passed me by. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because the error does not occur with the current MiKTeX (updated today) I add this as answer here.

I reduced the given MWE and added command `\listfiles`:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{bytefield}{32}
    \bitheader{0,8,16,24,32} \\
    \bitbox{16}{Kind} & \bitbox{16}{} \\
    \wordbox{3}{Payload} \\
\end{bytefield}
\end{figure}
```

Then TeXnicCenter shows me in the log area:

[image: TeXnicCenter log area]

and the `.log` file (only parts, with list of used packages and versions):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.7.19)  26 OCT 2015 21:05
entering extended mode
**275042.tex
(275042.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2 <=====================================
```

seems that MiKTeX does still use version 2015/01/01.
And the list of used packages:

```
 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
bytefield.sty    2014/06/03 v2.2 Network protocol diagrams
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 ***********
```

**Edit:**

If I use the complete given MVE, I get only 7 warnings, resulting from the usage of `titlesec` with KOMA-Script and one warning to better use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}`. No other error or warnings!

If needed I can add the complete `.log` file, here only the relevant parts with the warnings:

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
(scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrartcl)              I'd suggest to use the package only
(scrartcl)              if you really need it, because it breaks several
(scrartcl)              KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
(scrartcl)              the extended optional argument of the section
(scrartcl)              commands.
(scrartcl)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrartcl)              package `titlesec' on input line 19.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty"
Package: titlesec 2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box53
\beforetitleunit=\skip82
\aftertitleunit=\skip83
\ttl@plus=\dimen190
\ttl@minus=\dimen191
\ttl@toksa=\toks39
\titlewidth=\dimen192
\titlewidthlast=\dimen193
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen194


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected
(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected
(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected
(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected
(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.


Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected
(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.

)

Package scrartcl Warning: Activating an ugly workaround for a missing
(scrartcl)                feature of package `titlesec` on input line 19.
```

and

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider w
riting \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} into your preamble.
 on input line 20.

\height=\dimen197 (locally)
\depth=\dimen198 (locally)
\totalheight=\dimen199 (locally)
\width=\dimen200 (locally)
```

Used packages and versions:

```
 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
listings.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  framed.sty    2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
multirow.sty    
pgfplots.sty    2015/05/02 v1.12.1 Data Visualization (1.12.1)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environment
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
bytefield.sty    2014/06/03 v2.2 Network protocol diagrams
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
    ulem.sty    2012/05/18
  syntax.sty    1996/05/17 1.07 Syntax typesetting (MDW)
titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
275042-1.out
275042-1.out
 ***********
```

Comment: You'll need to try the full MWE to see the issue: you need to use up the 'standard pool' of dimens.

Comment: Force a format update :-)

Answer (score 0):

For automating setup of the build environment, such that recent TeX Live package versions do not conflict with these documents, I've added the following to my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN sed -i '1s/^/\\let\\locdimen\\newdimen\n/' \
    /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bytefield/bytefield.sty
```

with explanatory comments, and a note to remove this terrible hack the next time the [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) image is rebuilt, if the *bytefield* package has been "fixed" by then.

This does *effectively* tell LaTeX that the extended allocators are always to be used. :)