# TeXLive 2016 installer won't install collection-science?

Tags: texlive, installing

I am rebuilding one of my Docker images and a collection seems to have vanished. Although I name it in my profile, `collection-science` isn't being installed.

Can anyone tell me why?

The profile:

```
selected_scheme scheme-basic
TEXDIR /usr/local/texlive/2016
TEXMFCONFIG ~/.texlive2016/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME ~/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR ~/.texlive2016/texmf-var
option_doc 0
option_src 0
collection-fontsrecommended 1
collection-pictures 1
collection-science 1
collection-genericrecommended 1
collection-genericextra 1
collection-latex 1
collection-latexrecommended 1
collection-latexextra 1
```

The command and output:

```
./install-tl --profile=/staging/install-tl.profile
Automated TeX Live installation using profile: /staging/install-tl.profile
Loading http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
Installing TeX Live 2016 from: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
Platform: i386-linux => 'GNU/Linux on Intel x86'
Distribution: net  (downloading)
Using URL: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
Directory for temporary files: /tmp/gUkPYfsHfx
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2016
Installing [0001/1524, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 2up [5k]
Installing [0002/1524, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: ESIEEcv [2k]
Installing [0003/1524, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: GS1 [4k]
Installing [0004/1524, time/total: 00:00/00:00]: HA-prosper [28k]
[..]
Installing [0205/1524, time/total: 00:32/01:01]: cntformats [3k]
Installing [0206/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: cntperchap [4k]
Installing [0207/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: codedoc [10k]
Installing [0208/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: codepage [11k]
Installing [0209/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: codesection [3k]
Installing [0210/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: collcell [3k]
Installing [0211/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: collectbox [3k]
Installing [0212/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: collection-basic [1k]
Installing [0213/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: collection-fontsrecommended [1k]
Installing [0214/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: collection-genericextra [1k]
Installing [0215/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: collection-genericrecommended [1k]
Installing [0216/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: collection-latex [1k]
Installing [0217/1524, time/total: 00:33/01:03]: collection-latexextra [6k]
Installing [0218/1524, time/total: 00:34/01:05]: collection-latexrecommended [1k]
Installing [0219/1524, time/total: 00:34/01:05]: collection-pictures [2k]
Installing [0220/1524, time/total: 00:34/01:05]: colordoc [3k]
Installing [0221/1524, time/total: 00:34/01:05]: colorinfo [2k]
Installing [0222/1524, time/total: 00:34/01:05]: coloring [2k]
Installing [0223/1524, time/total: 00:34/01:05]: colorsep [2k]
[..]
Installing [1517/1524, time/total: 05:19/05:19]: yplan [7k]
Installing [1518/1524, time/total: 05:19/05:19]: yplan.i386-linux [1k]
Installing [1519/1524, time/total: 05:19/05:19]: zapfchan [79k]
Installing [1520/1524, time/total: 05:20/05:20]: zapfding [46k]
Installing [1521/1524, time/total: 05:20/05:20]: zed-csp [8k]
Installing [1522/1524, time/total: 05:21/05:21]: ziffer [2k]
Installing [1523/1524, time/total: 05:21/05:21]: zwgetfdate [2k]
Installing [1524/1524, time/total: 05:21/05:21]: zwpagelayout [9k]
Time used for installing the packages: 05:22
running mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist ...
writing fmtutil.cnf to /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
writing updmap.cfg to /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
writing language.dat to /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat
writing language.def to /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def
writing language.dat.lua to /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua
running mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist ...
running updmap-sys --nohash ...done
re-running mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config ...
pre-generating all format files, be patient...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex,mfluajit --no-strict --all ...done
running package-specific postactions
finished with package-specific postactions

 See
   /usr/local/texlive/2016/index.html
 for links to documentation.  The TeX Live web site
 contains updates and corrections: http://tug.org/texlive.

 TeX Live is a joint project of the TeX user groups around the world;
 please consider supporting it by joining the group best for you. The
 list of user groups is on the web at http://tug.org/usergroups.html.

 Add /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/info to INFOPATH.
 Add /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/man to MANPATH
   (if not dynamically found).

 Most importantly, add /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux
 to your PATH for current and future sessions.

 Welcome to TeX Live!
Logfile: /usr/local/texlive/2016/install-tl.log
```

I only spotted this because I'm still [patching `bytefield.sty`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275053/19604) (though not for long, as I've just discovered that the patch is no longer necessary), but its files are no longer present post-install so the `sed` command errors out.

Comment: Running an update here it's down as '`auto-remove`': I'm not sure it's deliberate but suggest raising on the TeX Live mailing list to get confirmation. (I have all of TL  installed so removing the collection doesn't affect my installed packages.)

Comment: @JosephWright: Okay; have asked there. Now the wait begins. In the meantime, our rebuild is blocked. :(

Comment: If you are setting up for automation and wanting a minimal system, I'd expect not to use the rather open concept of a collection but rather to have an explicit list of packages: your call of course.

Comment: @JosephWright: A reasonable suggestion — at some point I decided that the best balance for us was a hand-picked selection of collections that broadly gives us the packages we need, and that tend to include the packages we find ourselves wanting later. I didn't want to be _too_ minimal or I'd be rebuilding every few weeks when a doc author decides they need such-and-such a package. But, on the flip side, a full installation of TeXLive is far too unwieldy for our purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collections -mathextra and -science were merged into a new collection-mathscience. Updates will automatically install the new collection. For new installs using a profile you need to adjust the profile.

Comment: Was just coming to write this very answer. Karl Berry told me this on the `tex-live` mailing list. Sadly it means that every profile out there  using `collection-science` is now broken, and silently, at that, because there is no error message from the now-ignored collection. I have spent this afternoon fixing & rebuilding all of my build server images as a result. I can, at least, confirm that I now have the `bytefield` package once again after making the change.

Comment: As an aside, is there some place that breaking changes like this are announced? I need to subscribe to that.

Comment: Profiles are not supposed to be stable, at least we never said so. I agree that meeting math-extra into -science would have been better, but life is like this. And btw, it is not the first time that we changed collections.