# update beamer on ubuntu 14.0

Tags: beamer, ubuntu

I want to update only beamer as I have `beamer.cls` 2012/10/15 development version 3.24. I fear when updating TeXlive to have problems when compiling other tex files. What can I do to just update beamer? Thank you.

Comment: As `beamer` loads a large number of files behind the scenes, you may well run into [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) trying to 'only' update `beamer`.  More importantly: will you truly never update your TeX installation? That doesn't seem wise either.  Rather, if you are really worried about long-term viability of your files, it is probably better to make use of things like the `snapshot` package and/or `arlatex`. (I wrote an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116797/8528) about how to do this once.)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system covers in method 3 the general approach: download the `beamer` files and place them in your local tree. Does that help?

Comment: I have the problem posted here [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351729/beamerreduce-space-in-the-top-and-the-bottom-header-of-the-warsaw-template?noredirect=1#comment864266_351729] and updating beamer was suggested as a solution if I can solve it without updating beamer it will be the best for me

Comment: @jon There have been no changes in `beamer` over the time period concerned that are linked to dependencies: `beamer` does load other packages but is pretty conservative in using their features.

Comment: @JosephWright I downloaded the beamer package from [https://github.com/josephwright/beamer] but I don't know how to install it in my ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @amandana So you are using Linux: which part of the general instructions was unclear? You need to install into `~/texmf`. (BTW, I would recommend getting the `beamer` release version from CTAN rather than a random development version from GitHub!)

Comment: @JosephWright I don't understand how to install it :the instruction to write in the terminal. Sorry for my ignorance :( When i go to the ctan to download beamer it gives the link above . sorry again and thank you

Comment: I run LTS versions of ubuntu as well, and have been through this. I suggest that you uninstall the old version of LaTeX and reinstall the [latest TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).  It will probably save you time in the long run, especially if anything you do requires pgf/tikz

Comment: @ChrisH does updating latex alter my other files (dependencies ,...?) thank you

Comment: @amandana I don't believe LaTeX has any external dependencies as such.  There are scripts that require (e.g.) perl but these aren't prgrammed in as dependencies and any version of perl would do.

Comment: @ChrisH -- I think (but am not certain) what's amandana is worried about is that the LaTeX packages the `.tex` files load will have changed and this will impact on the resulting PDF (or PS, etc.). Generally, the answer is 'you'll probably be fine', but it is impossible to say a priori for all files for all times. The best LaTeX solution (in my opinion) for absolute stability is to use `snapshot` and `arlatex` (`beamer` docs will be quite large, however). Or go the Knuth route, of course.